# How to add using element to a Collection Set using Streams?

Tags: java, collections, set, java-stream

Currently I am adding an element to a Collection Set like this.

```
Set<Rental> currentFavouriteRentals = currentUser.getFavouriteRentals();
currentFavouriteRentals.add(rental);
currentUser.setFavouriteRentals(currentFavouriteRentals);
```

Is there a way to do this with Streams that does not use Stream.concat()?

Comment: No, not really.  Why do you want to use Streams when you already have a clear solution?

Comment: Stream work on all elements of collection for single operation ,where traversing is not required stream can't be use eg: to append element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to remodel the objects, you're updating `User`'s favorites outside
this should happen within the `User` class [Read this OO Principle, TellDon'tAsk](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)

```
class User {
    private Set<Rental> favoriteRentals;

    public User() {
        this.favoriteRentals = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public Set<Rental> updateFavoriteRentals(Rental rental) {
        this.favoriteRentals.add(rental);
        return this.favoriteRentals;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @HariHaravelan. You are correct. My User entity had bad OO design. Your way makes it simple to add Rental to the Set<Rental>

Comment: Good Answer. But for [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming), I would return an [unmodifiable set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable): `return Set.copyOf( this.favoriteRentals ) ;`

Answer (score 0):

Although this may not satisfy (or be appropriate for) your specific example, you **can** add elements to an existing stream using [mapMulti](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapMulti(java.util.stream.IntStream.IntMapMultiConsumer)) introduced in Java 16.  For example, the following will add the number 99999 to the stream before each even number.

```
Random r = new Random();
int [] arr = r.ints(10,1,100).mapMulti((val, consumer)-> {
    if (val%2==0) {
        consumer.accept(99_999);
    }
    consumer.accept(val);
}).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

prints something like

```
[99999, 80, 29, 95, 99999, 40, 65, 99999, 22, 23]
```

If you want to add it after each even number then accept the value first, then do the test for even parity.